# My website domain wont lead to my website even though the dns records are correct

Tags: dns, vercel

I am trying to connect my domain to my Vercel website, when i do it the nameservers and the dns records are correct and I still cant connect it says

This page isn’t workingwww.deathwishes.online redirected you too many times.
Try clearing your cookies.
ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS
I've cleared my cookies and it still wont work.

I expected to connect to my website.

Answer (score 0):

you are trying to redirect to yourself so you are stuck in an endless redirect loop. You need to make sure that your website does not redirect to itself.